# Can someone explain why my matrix subtraction is messing up the index?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

So I'm working on a regression model for the boston housing dataset, and for some reason when I try to subtract two 506x1 matrices in my gradient descent algorithm(prediction_error = np.subtract(y,prediction_function)
it's giving me a 506x506 matrix(prediction_error). I did the same operation twice before and nothing wrong happened. I tried to use the np.subtract instead of just using the regular minus sign in python, but nothing changed. Can someone help me?

```py
theta_grad = np.zeros((14,1))
print(theta_grad.shape) #debugging
prediction_function = X @ theta_grad 
print(prediction_function.shape) #debugging
prediction_error = np.subtract(y,prediction_function.reshape(y.shape))
print(prediction_error.shape) #debugging
gradient = X.T @ prediction_error
```

Comment: Please add your code an output as text. Screenshots of text are no acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please re-read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, e.g."***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.***" (emphasis in the original).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays `y` is of shape `(506,)` and the other is of shape `(506,1)` and python broadcast one over the other. Try reshaping them into similar shapes like this:

```
np.subtract(y,prediction_function.reshape(y.shape))
```

To see the effect, here is a sample code for better understanding:

```
A = np.arange(5) #shape (5,)
B = np.arange(5).reshape(5,1)  #shape (5,1)
np.subtract(A, B)

[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [-1  0  1  2  3]
 [-2 -1  0  1  2]
 [-3 -2 -1  0  1]
 [-4 -3 -2 -1  0]]   

np.subtract(A, B.reshape(A.shape))

[[0 0 0 0 0]]
```